# Using foreach loop to print all results

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I have got stuck on an each loop.

I'm trying to get the values from a variable with objects and when I print it using `alert()`, I get all the results.

But when I'm trying to print it to the HTML I only get the last result printed to the HTML instead of 3, in this case.

```
$.each(playlist, function(index, item) {
    alert(item.title);
    $('.playlist1').text(item.title);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you're not stuck on the `.each()` loop, you're stuck on `.text()`.

`.text()` replaces the current text with new text, so you'll only ever see the last one in this case.

Maybe use `.append()`.

You could also use `.text()` in this fashion:

```
$('.playlist1').text(function(index, text){
  return text + item.title;
});
```

Assuming `.playlist1` is a `ul` or `ol`, you can append to it like this:

```
$('.playlist1').append('<li>'+item.title+'</li>');
```

Comment: Hehe, thanks! You have to learn new things everyday and I just learned one! Thanks! :)

Comment: ahh, so it was index, thanx for making the sense out of it. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, it works pretty well. But as i said before i'm new to this type of things. If I want to loop out all results into list items how to I do that? Don't really get it to work.

Comment: @blytung, you would use `append('<li>'+item.title+'</li>')`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `append` function rather than `text`:

```
$('.playlist1').append(item.title);
```

`text()` replaces the contents of the element with the new content.  `append()` appends the new content to the existing contents of the element.

**Update**

To add each item as a list item do this:

```
$('.playlist1').append('<li>' + item.title + '</li>');
```

Comment: Thanks guys, it works pretty well. But as i said before i'm new to this type of things. If I want to loop out all results into list items how to I do that? Don't really get it to work.

Comment: @blytung, you would use `append('<li>'+item.title+'</li>')`

Comment: I've updated my answer to show adding the content as a list item.

Answer (score 1):

Using alert can interrupt the execution of the script, consider using console.log()

```
console.log(item.title);
```

An each loop iterates much like a foreach, in this case i is the iterator, and item is the value

```
$.each(playlist, function (i, item) {
```

When you iterate, you are setting the text of every element with "class=playlist1" to `item.title`.

```
 $('.playlist1').text(item.title);
});
```

Although nothing is wrong syntactically, there is a logical error. Perhaps you could try this:

```
var fulltext = [];//initialize empty array
$.each(playlist, function (i, item) {
 fulltext.push(item.title);//iterate through playlist and collect titles
}); 
$('.playlist1').text(fulltext.join(" "));//join array with titles with a blank space
                                         //and put them in class playlist1
```

you could do this for list items:

```
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
$.each(playlist, function (i, item) {
 var thisLi = document.createElement("li");
 thisLi.innerHTML = item;
 ul.appendChild(thisLi);
}); 
$('.playlist1').append(ul);
```